# How to access codeigniter method inside a controller using ajax

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I've made a codeigniter webiste and now I need to make an app. I want to call some of the controller methods using ajax. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#page2',
function(){
            $('#submit').click(function() 
            {
                var name = $("#username").val();
                var surname = $("#usersurname").val();

                alert(name + " " + surname);

                $.post(
                    "http://localhost:8080/bookbay/index.php/Home/test", 
                    {'name':name,'surname':surname},
                    function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data.name + " " + data.surname);
                    },
                    "json");
            });         
          });
```

The ajax all works up until the post. Then is just sends me back to the default app page and doesn't give me anything from the contoller. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is the code for the test function:

```
    class Home extends CI_Controller
{
        function test()
        {
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $surname = $this->input->post('surname');
            $array = array('name' => "*".$name."*", 'surname'=> "?".$surname."?");
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
```

Comment: can you post the code of test function?

Comment: Sounds like your form is being submitted before it gets to your AJAX submit code. Try adding `event.preventDefault();` to the top of your click function, and also add in `event` as a parameter. `$('#submit').click(function(event) {`, to prevent the form from submitting via http post.

Answer (score 0):

Change your post with this

```
$.post( 
    "<?php echo site_url('home/test')?>", 
    {'name':name,'surname':surname},
    function(data){alert(data.name + " " + data.surname);},
    "json"
);
```

Comment: I may have been a bit vague earlier. I'm using PhoneGap to make the app so the ajax is with in the android app and then its calling the Contoller method which is on my local host. I've tired the code you suggested and nothing comes back from the controller that is assuming I even manage to access the controller

Comment: @user1638809 - then this is not how to ask a question. and your way is wrong. you need to work with restuful web service for this